# I want to query a list of all clicks for the previous day and order them by the URL, but I can't get that to work?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

Here's the query I'm trying.  I'd like all similar URLs together so when I use some ampscript I can accurately dedupe them, but this isn't working.  Anyone have ideas what I might be doing wrong?

```
select top 100 percent 
JobID
, EventDate
, Domain
, URL
, substring(LinkName, 0, 1024) as 'LinkName'
, substring(LinkContent, 0, 4000) as 'LinkContent'
, IsUnique
from _Click
group by JobID, EventDate, Domain, URL, 'LinkName', 'LinkContent', IsUnique
where 
EventDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
AND where EventDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
AND EventDate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
order by URL
```

Comment: What's the exact error text you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I typically select unique clicks.

The inner select assigns a number to each row (`ranking`) by `subscriberid`, `jobid` and `url`.  The outer select returns only the highest ranked row per subscriber.

You had an extra `where` in your date criteria.  My example just selects clicks from yesterday.  Casting the `getDate()` to a `date` just strips off the time portion of the date.

```
select
  x.JobID
, x.EventDate
, x.Domain
, x.URL
, x.LinkName
, x.LinkContent
, x.IsUnique
from (
    select
      c.JobID
    , c.EventDate
    , c.Domain
    , c.URL
    , substring(c.LinkName, 0, 1024) as LinkName
    , substring(c.LinkContent, 0, 4000) as LinkContent
    , c.IsUnique
    , row_number() over(partition by c.subscriberid, c.jobid, c.url order by c.eventDate) ranking
    from _Click c
    where 
    /* yesterday */
    c.eventdate >= dateadd(day, -1, cast(getDate() as date))
    and c.eventdate < dateadd(day, 0, cast(getDate() as date))
    and c.isUnique = 1
) x
where x.ranking = 1
```

Comment: Part of the problem is I'm trying to order all the URL's in order.  The reason I'm trying to do this is that I have an email going out with ampscript that I'm trying to make mimic the click report so I need to dedupe the links so I can build a table. I found your blog link doing that but if all the same url's aren't together then the dedupe doesn't really work.

I could probably push all URL's into an array and dedupe that way but it's getting complicated when you add in counting total and unique clicks although maybe that will be easier to do in a second query and DE. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can order the URLs for use in AMPScript via LookupOrderedRows()  and order based on the URL field.  This makes life much easier for your needs than trying to order via SQL.

Comment: @Gortonington - I don't think that's going to help me out much.  That will give me the number of times a link got clicked in the URL, but it won't give me the unique links in the email and how many times were clicked.  I guess I can create another DE that just houses distinct URLs and use that for the LookupOrderedRows(), but I just woulda thought there was a better way.